# How to add a password in each task/playbook in the Ansible

Tags: ansible

I am doing automation using Ansible.

In the manual steps for each command it is asking for password (not `sudo` password).

How can I automate this manual step in Ansible?

```
Ex: Manual steps

    **mahesh-system#  command1**

Enter password: 

    **mahesh-system# command2** 

Enter password:
```

I have written playbook but it is not started executing, as per my knowledge it is looking for password (not `sudo` password). How can I implement this?

Ansible playbook:

```yaml
---

  name: health check start
  shell: command1
```

Comment: What command are you talking about? You can probably give the password as argument to that command.

Comment: Try [expect – Executes a command and responds to prompts.](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/expect_module.html#expect-executes-a-command-and-responds-to-prompts).

Comment: It's a project/server specific health checks

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments you could use the module [`expect`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/expect_module.html). You need to make sure that remote [Requirements](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/expect_module.html#requirements) are resolved and you have installed in example `python2-pexpect` and `python2-ptyprocess`.

```yaml
- name: Health check start
  expect:
    command: command1
    responses:
      (?i)Enter password: "{{ PASSWORD }}"
```